# Largest dimensional Lie subgroup of $SU(N)$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is the largest (Lie) subgroup of $SU(n)$ in the sense of its dimension.

I am aware of this potential duplicate [subgroup of SU(N) with maximal manifold dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16562/41654) , however, the title of this question doesn't exactly match the actual question asked or answered. It is mentioned that

"For n large enough it should be possible to prove that there are no more examples using classification of compact groups." - What is this proof and does it have a modern reference!

Comment: The answer of Victor Ostrik (the accepted answer) gives you all what you need assuming that you know the irreducible representation of least dimension of each simple group (Lie algebra). You can find this, for example, in Table 1 in: Onishchik, A. L.; Vinberg, È. B. Lie groups and algebraic groups. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990. See also Table 5 in this book.

Comment: As it stands with a little fiddling the answer to what I asked can be got from the answer to the other question. However, I'm still slightly unclear on the $SU(4)$ case? Will the max dim proper sub algebra have dim $(4-1)^2 = 9$ in this case? Is it just $\mathfrak{U}(3)$?

Comment: the refs here resolve it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118484/lie-subgroups-of-su4